# Splitting / Divide dataframe every 10 rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tuples, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to split my data frame into 10 rows and find the aggregate function (mean, SD, etc) for each 10 rows then merge it into 1 data frame again. Previously I had grouped the data using `.groupby` function, but having trouble to split the data into 10 rows.

This is what I have done :

```
  def sorting (df):
    grouped = df.groupby(['Activity']).
    l_grouped=list(grouped)
```

I turned the grouped result into list (l_grouped), but I don't know if I could separate the rows from each tuple/list?
The result was indentical with the original data frame, but there were separated by 'Activity'. For example, row that has 'Standing' as the targeted value ('Activity')  would be accesible through calling l_grouped[1][0] (type list/tuple). l_grouped [1][1] would return word 'Standing' only.
I could access the grouped result using :

```
  for i in range(len(df_sort)):
      print(df_sort[i][1])
```

df_sort referring to the result of calling the `sorting(df)`
Is there any way i could split/divide the tuple/list per each rows? Then create the aggregate function out of that?

Comment: Please post sample input and expected output for clarity.

Comment: hello, i've edited the question. I hope it gives you more clarity regarding my question

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a window function + a small trick for the stride:

```
step = 10
window = 10

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(100)})
df['a'].rolling(window).sum()[::step]
```

if this is not the exact result you are looking for check the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) for more details regarding the bounds of the window and etc. ...

Comment: why the range is 100?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```py
import numpy as np

step = 10
df["id"] = np.arange(len(df))//step

gr = df.groupby("id")
...
```